# Confirm message or separate vote buttons?

Tags: usability, mobile-web

There is a website similar to reddit where users can write messages, and vote them.

Due technical reasons, when a user votes a message, their vote cannot be undone.

The problem is that in mobile version, sometimes the users misses the button and vote down when they wanted to vote up.

Now I found two options:

- Separate more the buttons "vote up" and "vote down"
- Add a confirm message where vote down saying something like "Are you sure that you want to vote down?

Which is more usable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something you could apply is a slide control, similar to that of answering a call or locking up the screen. If you use the entire width of the screen for the control the amount of unintentional votes could be kept to a minimum, and the action is performed in one operation/gesture.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqdlO9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: + I like this.  If activating a small indicator on screen invoked a full screen overlay with the full screen control, that would be slick.  Of course, a cancel button might be helpful, but certainly not necessary if the device's built in back button was adequate and available.

Comment: @JustinC Thanks for the feedback! I believe the OP was looking for a solution that could be integrated into the feed of content, without being arranged in an additional view (overlay/popup/modal). In a list view that utilize the entire viewport width you could use this control at full width without having it in another expandable window.

Answer (score 3):

> Due to *technical reasons*, when a user votes a message, their vote
>   cannot be undone.

Clearly, allowing a vote to be undone is optimal from the user's point of view.  It seems that technical decisions are inappropriately driving the functionality of the program.  *If it is under your control*, why not fix the underlying problem, instead of spending your time on a work-around that won't really be satisfactory?

Allowing a user to come back and change a vote at any time may be quite disruptive to your design.  However, all that is really needed here is the ability to change the vote for a short period of time (10 or 15 seconds).  I suggest implementing a short pause before the vote is officially recorded, and allowing the vote to be changed during that time.

Comment: Maybe they use a third party solution and only have an interface to work with which doesn't allow reroll of votes. I don't know, but that could be the case

Comment: @AndroidHustle, fair enough.  I added qualification to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, less steps are better, so I would go for the first option.

The next problem is how would you effectively present the separation to the user. The separation should be presented in a manner relatively close to its desktop-version. The intent is you want your user to still feel that the mobile version, is really the mobile version and will not go finding where the other "Vote"-button is.

If you could provide a mock-up or screenshots that would benefit this discussion.